# .Include() still queries database after a ToList()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following View defined in my Context class, Entity Framework: I have added `.Include()` here, with the hopes that this will eliminate calls to database later.

```
public IQueryable<GeneralReportModel> vwGeneralReportItems
    {
        get
        {
            return from p in this.Patients.AsNoTracking().Include(p => p.Age) //Multiple includes added to include all properties on model

                   join fac in this.Facilities.AsNoTracking() on p.FacilityID equals fac.ID into fJoin
                   from f in fJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()

                   join userFac in this.UserFacilities.AsNoTracking() on p.FacilityID equals userFac.FacilityID into ufJoin
                   from uf in ufJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()

                   select new GeneralReportModel()
                   {
                       Patient = p,
                       //ReportIndex = ri,
                       Facility = f,
                       UserFacility = uf
                   };
        }
    }
```

I also have this function, which does some filtering on my select from the View:

```
private IQueryable<GeneralReportModel> generalReportQuery(ApplicationTypes.ReportParameterObject repParam)
    {
        var reportQuery = ReportHelper.GeneralReport_Source(this.DbContext, repParam, false);
        reportQuery = ReportHelper.GeneralReport_FilterCriteria(this.DbContext, reportQuery, repParam);

        // Lab confirmed - Extra Pulmonary 
        reportQuery = reportQuery.Where(rq =>
            rq.Patient.TypeOfResistantTBConfirmation.Value == ApplicationTypes.ResistantTBConfirmationTypes.LABCONFIRMED.ToString() &&
            rq.Patient.SiteOfDiseaseID != repParam.DatabaseSettingObject.SiteOfDiseaseID_ExtraPulmonary && 
            rq.Patient.PatientCategoryID != ApplicationGlobal.GLBDATABASESETTINGOBJECT.PatientCategoryID_TransferIn);

        return reportQuery;
    }
```

The code below

```
var reportQueryMdr = reportQuery.Where(rq =>
            rq.Patient.TypeOfResistantTB.Value == ApplicationTypes.ResistantTBTypes.MDR.ToString());

        var list = reportQueryMdr.ToList();
        foreach (var obj in list)
        {
            obj.ReportIndex = obj.Patient.getRecalculatedReportIndexFields(ApplicationGlobal.GLBDATABASESETTINGOBJECT);
        }

        reportQueryMdr = list.AsQueryable();
```

Still calls the Database for each iteration made over the list. How can I make this list entirely reside in memory, with all the Patient properties.